# Casting geometry to MULTI using GeoPandas?

Tags: geopandas

Shapefiles can mix simple `POLYGON`s and `MULTIPOLYGON`s in the same data source. Spatial databases like PostGIS and SpatiaLite are strict, and will not put a `POLYGON` in a `MULTIPOLYGON` geometry column.

I've gotten used to using [`ST_Multi`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Multi.html) to fix this issue. But now I am trying to use GeoPandas to do some file processing, including converting from shapefile to GeoPackage (with a bunch of stuff in the middle), and I am running into this error:

```py
gdf.to_file("garbage.gpkg", "GPKG")
```

```
ValueError: Record's geometry type does not match collection schema's 
   geometry type: 'MultiPolygon' != 'Polygon'
```

Is there a GeoPandas equivalent to `ST_Multi` that I can use to fix the geometry before saving to the GeoPackage or SpatiaLite format?

Comment: Shapefile isn't *sloppy* so much as it *doesn't care*.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

**TL;DR**

Given a geopandas data frame `gdf` with mixed Polygons and MultiPolygons, the geometry column can be converted to Multi with the following:

```py
from shapely.geometry.polygon import Polygon
from shapely.geometry.multipolygon import MultiPolygon

gdf["geometry"] = [MultiPolygon([feature]) if isinstance(feature, Polygon) \
    else feature for feature in gdf["geometry"]]
```

## More info:

There doesn't appear to be an equivalent of PostGIS's `ST_Multi` that can accept a Polygon or a MultiPolygon, and casts to Multi while not harming geometries that are *already* Multi.

### The problem with casting to `Multi` without checking the input type

The `MultiPolygon` contructor requires a list of polygons. If the feature is a Polygon, the feature has to be wrapped in list brackets: `MultiPolygon([feature])`. Otherwise, `MultiPolygon(feature)` throws the following error:

```
TypeError: 'Polygon' object is not iterable
```

If the feature is already a MultiPolygon, `MultiPolygon(feature)` is harmless, but `MultiPolygon([feature])` will extract only *one* polygon part from the multipart feature, and drop all others.

### The solution

Hence, the type must be determined first, and `MultiPolygon` only applied to non-Multi features (e.g., simple Polygons). The list comprehension above:

1. Extracts each feature with `for feature in gdf["geometry"]`.
2. Checks if it is a Polygon with `if isinstance(feature, Polygon)`.
3. Passes Polygons only to the MultiPolygon constructor with `MultiPolygon([feature])`.
4. Returns the feature untouched with `else feature` for features which are already MultiPolygons.
5. Assigns back to the geometry column with `gdf["geometry"] =`

Comment: FYI `isinstance(object, type)` is preferred to using `type(object)` since `isinstance` fails with subclasses.

Answer (score 0):

I've made an extension to GeoSeries, using [Pandas api extension](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.api.extensions.register_series_accessor.html), that works similar to ST_Multi in PostGIS. The extension is not really needed for this problem, but it is convenient if you want to add even more functionallity to GeoSeries.

```
import pandas
import shapely.geometry
from geopandas import GeoSeries

# Imports for the examples 
from shapely.geometry import Point, MultiPoint, LineString, MultiLineString, Polygon, MultiPolygon, GeometryCollection


# Adding a geoaccessor
# For more info: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.api.extensions.register_series_accessor.html
@pandas.api.extensions.register_series_accessor("geom")
class GeoAccessor:
    def __init__(self, series: GeoSeries):
        self._s = series

    def make_multi(self, inplace: bool = False):
        geoms = []
        for i, s in self._s.items():
            # Getting the geometry type
            tp = s.geom_type
            if not tp[0:5] == 'Multi' and tp != 'GeometryCollection':
                # Getting the shapely Multi* function for the geometry type
                func = getattr(shapely.geometry, 'Multi' + tp)
                geoms.append(func([s]))
            else:
                geoms.append(s)
        r = GeoSeries(geoms)

        if inplace:
            self._s.iloc[:] = r
        else:
            return r


# EXAMPLES #
# Points:
points = [Point([1, 2]), MultiPoint([[1, 2], [1, 1]])]
gs = GeoSeries(points)
gs.geom.make_multi(inplace=True)  # Demonstrating inplace
print(gs)

# Lines:
lines = [LineString([[1, 2], [2, 3]]), MultiLineString([[[1, 2], [2, 3]], [[2, 3], [3, 4]]])]
gs = GeoSeries(lines)
print(gs.geom.make_multi())

# Polygons:
polygon = [Polygon([[0, 0], [1, 0], [1, 1], [0, 1], [0, 0]]),
           MultiPolygon([
               [
                   [[0, 0], [1, 0], [1, 1], [0, 1], [0, 0]],
                   [[[2, 2], [3, 2], [3, 3], [2, 3], [2, 2]]]
               ]
           ])]
gs = GeoSeries(polygon)
print(gs.geom.make_multi())

# GeometryCollections:
gc = [GeometryCollection([points[0], lines[0], polygon[1]]),
      GeometryCollection([points[1], lines[1], polygon[0]])]
gs = GeoSeries(gc)
print(gs.geom.make_multi())

# Mix:
gs = GeoSeries([points[0], lines[0], polygon[1]])
print(gs.geom.make_multi())
```