# Loading GeoDataFrame to PostGIS when GEOM column contains MULTILINESTRING and LINESTRING

Tags: postgis, postgresql, geopandas, pandas

How can I load GeoDataFrame (populated from shapefile) to PostGIS when GEOM column contains MULTILINESTRING and LINESTRING e.g.:

```
LINESTRING (14.2384666 46.6304714, 14.2386703 46.6304123)

MULTILINESTRING ((13.90433020000000042 46.61830880000000121, 13.90393929999999934 46.61873270000000247, 13.90390771785250124 46.61876445408692859),(13.90327032848085764 46.61940531353186401, 13.90327032848085587 46.61940531353186401))
```

I have tried with "to_sql" but I need to specify GEOM type and when I chose

```
'geom':Geometry('MULTILINESTRING', srid=4326)}
```

I got an error: *ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.ProgrammingError) can't adapt type 'LineString'*

Comment: Try `'geom':Geometry('GEOMETRY', srid=4326)}`.

Comment: I have tried. It did not work.

Comment: Can you post your code?

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the MultiLinestring first.

```
GeoDataframe.explode()
GeoDataframe.to_sql()
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on answer from [Casting geometry to MULTI using GeoPandas?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/311320/casting-geometry-to-multi-using-geopandas) I have found solution:

```
from shapely.geometry.linestring import LineString
from shapely.geometry.multilinestring import MultiLineString

geodataframe['geometry'] = [MultiLineString([feature]) if type(feature) == LineString else feature for feature in geodataframe['geometry']]
```